How to configure Casbin for user roles with domains
I'd like to use a policy like this:
# Define the permissions associated with each role
p, role1, Direct, read
p, role1, Direct, write

p, role2, Representative, read
p, role2, Representative, write

# Assign users to roles with domains
g, paul, role1, /marketplace/US/*
g, paul, role1, /marketplace/DE/*
g, charly, role2, /marketplace/*

So the request would be like (paul, write, Direct, /marketplace/DE/123).
First it looks up paul and sees that he has role1 access in domains /marketplace/US/* and /marketplace/DE/*. Then it sees that role1 is associated with read and write access to Direct. So this request would return True because user paul has write access to resource Direct at domain /marketplace/DE/* which matches the domain in the request.
We've been back and forth through the documentation but this seems a bit more complex that the examples there and we can't figure out the correct model.
It is similar to the "RESTful (KeyMatch)" example at https://casbin.org/editor/, but that example doesn't have any roles.
I've tried everything. I tried dividing the roles into two like this:
g, paul, role1
g, paul, role1
g, charly, role2
g2, paul, /marketplace/US/*
g2, paul, /marketplace/DE/*
g2, charly, /marketplace/*

but you lose which domain is associated with which role.
